# mod_rewrite issues with URL if page title has dashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page that is normally like this:

```
http://www.url.com/folder/content.php?name=this-is-the-page-title&item_id=129
```

As you can see, the title of the page is included in the URL, separated by dashes.

So, I'd like to convert this to the following with mod_rewrite:

```
http://www.url.com/this-is-the-page-title-129.html
```

For this, I use a mod_rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /folder/content.php?name=$1&item_id=$2 [L]
```

Unfortunately, using that rule, I get a 404 error. I think the problem is because the title is separated by dashes (-) and the separator itself is a dash as well, so it likely can't tell the variables from each other or something like that.

When I change the rule from dash (-) to slash (/) like this it works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)\.html$ /folder/content.php?name=$1&item_id=$2 [L]
```

But then the URL becomes:

```
http://www.url.com/this-is-the-page-title/129.html
```

...which I don't want as I'd have to rewrite the entire structure of the page.

Is there any way to get it working as

```
http://www.url.com/this-is-the-page-title-129.html
```

even with the page title being separated by dashes?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you specify `([^-]*)` which means that the matching sub-pattern should not contain any dashes... but your page title might contain them.

So, instead, lets let the first part by *anything* but slash:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ /folder/content.php?name=$1&item_id=$2 [L]
```

This way, everything before the last dash will go into the first sub-pattern, and digits after the last dash - into the second one.